# Error: Internal error regarding the lengths of vectors of coefficients in R

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I am trying to build a coefficient plot for the regression

```
est_bidders = feols(applied_participants ~ treatment_group::qt('18/02') | fe1 + fe2 + fe3, data)
```

`coefplot(est_bidders)`

And I am getting a strange error: `Error in coefplot_prms(object = object, ..., sd = sd, ci_low = ci_low,  : Internal error regarding the lengths of vectors of coefficients`

I actually don't get what it means and how I can correct it. When I run the same regression for other outcome variables, it works fine and in the end I get the desired graphs. Probably it has something to do with variable itself (it basically contains numbers from a range of 1 to 86)

UPDATE. Based on the comments below I provide some dput() for reproduction:

```
> dput(subset[1:15,])
```

`structure(list(applied_participants = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L), treatment_group = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), qt = c("16/01", "16/02", 
"16/02", "16/02", "16/02", "16/02", "16/02", "16/02", "16/02", 
"16/03", "16/03", "16/03", "16/03", "16/03", "16/03"), good_class = c("27", 
"17", "22", "20", "43", "10", "45", "27", "43", "26", "22", "26", 
"26", "26", "26"), customerrequirement_customer_regnum = c("01012000073", 
"01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", 
"01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", 
"01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073", "01012000073"), 
    year_month = c("2016-02", "2016-04", "2016-04", "2016-04", 
    "2016-04", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-06", "2016-07", 
    "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-09")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002551ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))`

I am using the following library to compute my regression and plot coefficients:

```
install.packages('fixest')
library(fixest)
```

And in the situation with these exact variables I am running a regression:

```
est_bidders = feols(applied_participants ~ treatment_group::qt('18/02') | good_class + customerrequirement_customer_regnum + year_month, subset)
```

The regression seems to work okay, but then a coefplot doesn't work with the named mistake
`coefplot(est_bidders)`

Comment: Can you create  a column with `data$newcol <- treatment_group::qt(data$'18/02')` and use that in the formula `feols(applied_participants ~newcol| fe1 + fe2 + fe3, data)`

Comment: Or may be change the single quote to backquote.  WIthout a small reproducible example wiith the packages used, it is not clear

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion! Creating a new column doesn't help, but what do you mean by changing the single quote to backquote?

Comment: you had '18/02', if yyou change it to `18/02` (backquotes), It is better to provide a small example with all packages used.  Also, couldn't find the package 'treatment_group'

Comment: Thanks! I provided the example and the code I was using. I am quite new here, so, I am not sure if this is enough

Comment: The part `treatment_group::qt` is not clear as I can't install that 'treatment_group' package.  There is a `qt` function in base R

Comment: These are just the names of the columns (which I also provide in dataput(), not the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fixest` author here. A few comments:

- `treatment_group::qt('18/02')` is actually a shorthand for `interact(treatment_group, qt, ref = "18/02")`. The `variable::interaction` syntax is highly non-standard R, I introduced it because I find it convenient but it is extremely confusing to persons not acquainted to it (especially that in the example above the *variable* name `qt` is also an R function...)
- You found an internal bug. The error you've bumped into should **never** occur, so there's something I didn't catch. Could you create an issue at https://github.com/lrberge/fixest/issues with a minimal working example? Or just send me an email? I'll correct it in the next update of the package.